# How to keep an entry in the database when deleting a row with foreign key

Tags: sql, ruby

I have my database setup like this:

```
CREATE TABLE farms
(
  id SERIAL8 primary key,
  name VARCHAR(255) not null,
  address VARCHAR(255),
  phone_num VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE products
(
  id SERIAL8 primary key,
  name VARCHAR(255) not null,
  description VARCHAR(255),
  stock FLOAT,
  cost FLOAT,
  price FLOAT,
  farm_id INT8 references farms(id)
)
```

The issue that I have is when I delete a farm, it's also deleting all of the products that are available in that farm, but I only want to delete the farm, and not the product.

This is the method I have that deletes the farm

```
  def delete
    sql = "DELETE FROM farms WHERE id = $1"
    values = [@id]
    SqlRunner.run(sql, values)
  end
```

Is the problem with how I'm building the tables, or is my SQL statement incorrect?

Comment: mysql <> sql-server <> postgresql. I removed the conflicting tags, please just add the revelant one.

Comment: Why *would* you want this behaviour? If you don't want the product deleted then you have to turn cascading (or the RDBMS equivalent functionality) off, however, a `FOREIGN KEY` that references a foreign key that doesn't exist is an untrusted foreign key, and therefore a *pointless* `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is by design. Not removing the products will result in orphaned records which can waste space and make a database inefficient or worse, return wrong results. I'd recommend reading some database design tutorials.

Comment: Maybe you want a linking table for products and farms, so that a product can independently exist with none, one, or more than one farm producing it? Or is every product special to a farm? In that case it doesn't make sense to keep the product if the farm goes down. There's no one to produce it anymore.

Comment: most sql databases allow other behaviours, for instance you cour try ON DELETE SET NULL